# Chinese Idiom puzzle 14 (中文填字遊戲)

Tags: idioms, games, puzzle

Please solve the following puzzle

[image]

1. Untidy (of one's appearance)
2. Too poor that there is no place to insert an awl. Describes as poor as nothing
3. It is the collective name of the three most prominent official positions in ancient times.
   (after the Qin Dynasty, it was mostly honorary titles without real power.)
4. An extremely brief moment
5. Cooperate
6. selfish
7. People in the world are all family
8. Cannot stand each other
9. Treat only the symptoms but not the root cause
10. A magical fruit in 西遊記
11. The largest large-scale anti-Qing movement in China in the mid-19th century
12. Fight to rule China
13. You will not succeed if you rush
14. The sky is high, the ground is thick
15. Important
16. Cheer on
17. see picture below

[image]

18. Complement each other and highlight their respective advantages
19. Panic
20. This time is different from that time
21. Frugal
22. Unavoidable
23. When hitting a dog, consider who the owner is.
24. Suicide
25. Foul language
26. Convenience
27. Acting on the side of justice, you will get much more support and help
28. Law
29. Control the weather

A. Not decent; nondescript

B. Not being cautious, making the other party be alerted

C. Calm

D. Everyone in the commercial world speaks from a commercial standpoint

E. Fill in the objects to be 修， 齊， 治， 平

F. Grammar

G. No one is spared

H. Barren land

I. Electricity

J. Treat one preferentially and ignore the other.

K. No need to ask for permission or help

L. Reflected light

M. Don't seek the essence of things, only pay attention to the minor details

N. Capture everyone in one move

O. Be on the lookout

P. Arson

Q. A tiny spark can ignite a vast field

R. Able to get anything one wanted (being very powerful)

S. Feel extremely ashamed

T. The more you cover it up, the more suspicious it seems

U. Princess

V. Redundant

W. Uneven; jagged

X. Miss the chance to see each other

Y. Gross profit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. 不修边幅
2. 贫无立锥
3. 三公
4. 电光石火
5. 齐心协力
6. 自私自利
7. 四海一家
8. 水火不容
9. 治标不治本
10. 人参果
11. 太平天国
12. 逐鹿中原
13. 欲速不达
14. 天高地厚
15. 重要
16. 打气
17. 弥勒
18. 相得益彰
19. 惊慌
20. 此一时彼一时
21. 悭吝
22. 在所难免
23. 打狗也要看主人面
24. 自尽
25. 污言秽语
26. 方便
27. 得道多助
28. 法律
29. 呼风唤雨

A. 不三不四

B. 打草惊蛇

C. 平心静气

D. 在商言商

E. 修身齐家治国平天下

F. 语法

G. 无一幸免

H. 不毛之地

I. 电力

J. 厚此薄彼

K. 自便

L. 反光

M. 舍本逐末

N. 一网打尽

O. 望风

P. 纵火

Q. 星火燎原

R. 要风得风，要雨得雨

S. 无地自容

T. 欲盖弥彰

U. 公主

V. 多余

W. 参差不齐

X. 缘悭一面

Y. 毛利

Please note I'm using simplified Chinese and the characters in the original crosswords are in traditional Chinese. But they should be compatible.

Comment: Good job, #21. is 悭俭( = 节俭), not 悭吝 (= 吝啬); #4. is 电光石火, you got #p. 纵火. so it is simply a mistake in the character order; Since you got #16, 逐鹿中原, you should answer #M. as 捨本逐末